# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in dropdown - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have populated a dynamic dropdown as this:

```
$scope.idSelectionModel = [];
$http({
        'url': '/getIds',
        'method': 'POST',
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(
        function(
            response) {
            $scope.idResponse = response.data;

            angular.forEach($scope.idResponse, function(value, key) {
                $scope.idSelectionModel.push({
                    id: value
                });
            });
        });

$scope.identity = $scope.idSelectionModel[0];

console.log($scope.idSelectionModel);
```

`$scope.idResponse` returns a list, which I have modified a little to map separate ids to the list element. But there are 3 behaviors which I notice:

1. Dropdown having an empty item as the first element.
2. The `console.log` is printing an empty array list with length as 0, even when there is data inside the list.
3. When I try printing  `$scope.identity.id`, I get an exception "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in dropdown".

Can someone please guide me on this?

Comment: `$http` returns a promise, the resolution of which is asynchronous. Therefore, your code continues on to the `$scope.identity = $scope.idSelectionModel[0];` line before the `.then()` function runs. You need to move those two lines inside the `.then()` function.

Comment: Great Lex! Thanks. The array is now resolved. But the exception is still prevalent. When I try to access this object like `$scope.identity.id` outside the loop, it throws the error. How can I access outside the loop?

Comment: In case, if need to use this scope inside an other method like mentioned above(outside the loop), this is throwing an exception.

Comment: With the code you have posted it's not possible to understand what "outside the loop" means.

Comment: I have another call to spring controller, that is outside .then() function, that performs:  `var data = {              'identity' : $scope.identity.id                 };` as paramter to the spring controller.

Comment: Need to use this id in that function call. On calling the function, and on trying to access this scope variable, I get the exception specified.

Comment: You have to write your code to work with the asynchronous nature of these calls. There's no silver bullet that solves it all and each particular situation may have its own unique solution.

Comment: Got it Lex. Thanks :)